# Parsing error in Unity Monodevelop

Tags: performance

im using unity3d monodevelop and it says i have parsing error i don't know where help !!

Here is the code

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerPhysics))]
public class Player Controller : MonoBehaviour {

```
// Player Handling
public float speed = 8;
public float acceleration = 30;

private float currentSpeed;
private float targetSpeed;
private Vector2 amountToMove;

private PlayerPhysics playerPhysics;


void Start () {
    playerPhysics = GetComponent<PlayerPhysics>();
}

void Update () {
    targetSpeed = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * speed;
    currentSpeed = IncrementTowards(currentSpeed, targetSpeed,acceleration);

    if (playerPhysics.grounded) {
        amountToMove.y = 0;

    }
    playerPhysics.Move(amountToMove * Time.deltaTime);
}

// Increase n towards target by speed
private float IncrementTowards(float n, float target, float a) {
    if (n == target) {
        return n;   
    }
    else {
        float dir = Mathf.Sign(target - n); // must n be increased or decreased to get closer to target
        n += a * Time.deltaTime * dir;
        return (dir == Mathf.Sign(target-n))? n: target; // if n has now passed target then return target, otherwise return n
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think your class name

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerPhysics))] public class Player Controller : MonoBehaviour {
```

caused the parsing error.

Try changing it to:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerPhysics))] public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
```

without the space.

Change the file name too (without space) as it needs to match the class name.